# Understanding custom completion handlers

Tags: objective-c, callback, objective-c-blocks, completionhandler

I wrote and used a little completion handler just to practice nailing down blocks -

```
-(void)delayAndSetCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL))completed {
    //set a delay timer
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
        completed(YES);
    });
}
```

In a VC elsewhere, I check the completion variable; if the block has completed, I change the background color to something else.

My question is this - in the method `delayAndSetCompletionBlock`, we have an argument that is a block. The block has a return type of void, takes a `Bool` as a parameter, and the BLOCK argument is called completed. How does this relate to further down in the code where I state `completed(YES)`?

I'm just confused as to what `completed(YES)` has to do with the block that I've passed in as a method argument. `completed` is the name of the block type being passed to the method, so am I saying "execute the block that we gave the method, and pass `YES` as the boolean parameter it takes"? If so, how does the block know what to do with that `YES`?

Comment: I assume that the comment "// code to be...." is a placeholder for the code that will be executed after a short delay. The last thing that delayAndSetCompletionBlock: will do is call the block that it was given as an argument. If you can imagine a circumstance in the placeholder code where something goes wrong, you might call completed(NO) there. The block called on completion can use the BOOL parameter to see if the code really did complete.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a method with single argument, named `completed`. This argument is a block, that returns `void` and expects single `BOOL` argument, unnamed in your case.

You can provide block argument name for clearance, although it's not used in code. Also, you can rename block to avoid confusion:

```
-(void)delayAndSetCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL completed))completionBlock;
```

So, your guess

> so am I saying "execute the block that we gave the method, and pass
>   YES as the boolean parameter it takes"?

was correct.

> If so, how does the block know what to do with that "YES"?

Caller of your method will usually provide block implementation. For example:

```
[self delayAndSetCompletionBlock:^void (BOOL completed) {
    if (completed) {
        NSLog(@"done!");
    }
}];
```

He will have some expectations about what your method does. If your method is public, hopefully you will document it, and specify when `completionBlock` will be called, and what is the meaning of block argument. Maybe, you will at least provide comment in header file. Also, it's possible, that code is self-documented, so any developer with Objective-C experience will expect similar behavior and block arguments meaning.

Comment: I guess my confusion lies in invoking the block. In the block implementation, we're setting the boolean to YES no matter what object invokes the block. When we invoke the block (in a VC, for example), we pass a block that has the same return type and parameter as the block in our defined method (delayAndSetCompletionBlock). It will jump to the original implementation of the block (where we set the completion bool equal to YES) no matter WHAT we do with the block in the VC, right? This is ultimately how it works.

Comment: With blocks in general, we can define them somewhere and choose to do NOTHING with the arguments, and instead, when we call that block somewhere, do something with the arguments THERE (like in a VC)? But in this case, we actually originally manipulate one of the arguments in the initial implementation, and that is the essence of a completion block?

Comment: Not sure that I understand you correctly. Just to make sure: Block body is not executed at point, when `delayAndSetCompletionBlock ` invoked. It's executed only when block called inside of method implementation. After that, we have a way to pass any data from method implementation to point, where method invoked through block arguments. This data is not available outside of block body.

Comment: My question was more about when we define -(void)delayAndSetCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL completed))completionBlock;

At the end of some process, we call the block (which takes a boolean argument), and pass it an argument of YES. My question is, what happens to that "YES"? Say we have Method A that takes an argument of type string; inside of the implementation, we have a blank method - it returns void and doesn't do anything.

 and inside of viewDidLoad we call [Method A: @"testing"] - nothing happens. This is like the completion block - we gave it a boolean, but didn't do anything with it.

Comment: So that is why I'm confused - how is it that we're checking to see if a Boolean value is set to YES (in the VC)? All we did in the delay method was call the block and pass it an argument of "YES". We didn't set any variable equal to YES, we just passed an argument to it but didn't actually do anything with it.